# After logging out I am unable to log back in, Keep getting redirected to "mysite/remove-group-member.icepush". Why?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, vaadin

I'm using tomcat and whenever I log out of my web app and try to log back in I get redirected to mysite/remove-group-member.icepush and I'm not sure why.  If I logout, refresh the page, then login everything works fine. Also if I hit the back button after being redirected to /remove-group-member.icepush I am logged in and at the main page of my app.

Can someone tell me why this is happening or how to fix it?

edit: I am using the IcePush Add on for Vaadin.

Comment: Have you set the logout URL? And, do you use the IcePush addon?

Comment: Yes I am using the IcePush Add on and I have set tried setting the logout url to my default address and null (which from what i read would set it to the default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be happening to all objects on the page.  To fix this on logout we remove all elements from the page and then terminate the sessions and redirect to the login screen.